# Generic Function without Input Parameter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a generic Swift function like this:

```
func toNSArray<T>() -> [T] {
...
}
```

The compiler gives no error but I do not know how to call this function. I tried:

```
jList.toNSArray<String>()
jList.<String>toNSArray()
```

but it did not work.

**How do I call a Generic function in Swift without input parameters?**

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but this function makes me nervous for two reasons – one is, it’s called `toNSArray` but it returns a Swift array not an `NSArray`.  The other is that it looks like it might fail if the contained types aren’t all `T`, but the return type is non-optional (though maybe it only populates the array with the values that _can_ be coerced to `T`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to tell Swift what the return type needs to be through some calling context:

```
// either
let a: [Int] = jList.toNSArray()

// or, if you aren’t assigning to a variable
someCall( jList.toNSArray() as [Int] )
```

Note, in the latter case, this would only be necessary if `someCall` took a vague type like `Any` as its argument.  If instead, `someCall` is specified to take an `[Int]` as an argument, the function itself provides the context and you can just write `someCall( jList.toNSArray() )`

In fact sometimes the context can be very tenuously inferred!  This works, for example:

```
extension Array {
    func asT<T>() -> [T] {
        var results: [T] = []
        for x in self {
            if let y = x as? T {
                results.append(y)
            }
        }
        return results
    }
}


let a: [Any] = [1,2,3, "heffalump"]

// here, it’s the 0, defaulting to Int, that tells asT what T is...
a.asT().reduce(0, combine: +)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the last line of your answer?

Comment: You mean the `reduce`?  `reduce` is a function that boils arrays down to single values.  Here, it’s taking an array of integers, and a starting value of zero, and then successively combining them together with the supplied function (in this case, `+`), resulting in the number 6.  Since `+` and 0 must mean the numbers are integers, the type returned by `asT` can be inferred to be an integer.